# Globalization with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

I am trying to localize my web page, and have done the following :

Added resource files with some example strings

Added a call to a method to set culture and ui culture on the click event of flag icons :

```
public void SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    }
```

And I have made reference to my resource file strings in my web page :

@Resources.General.String1

I have stepped through my code and the culture is successfully changed in my SetCulture method, but the string does not change on the web page.  Can anybody advise why?

Comment: do you use ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: you need to reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean with the click event in a ASP.NET MVC application. I would use routing to set the new language. A sample you can find at [Localization with ASP.NET MVC using Routing](http://www.alebo.de/2009/03/localization-with-aspnet-mvc-using-routing/).

Instead of using a Javascript event, you have to reload the whole page.

Comment: I am refering to a Javascript click event on a flag image, that I am using to call the method I showed in my post

Comment: But how should the page be updated when you have only a Javascript event? Somehow you have to reload the content.